# Out of memory after Android Update on Galaxy S2

Tags: android, memory, upgrade, out-of-memory, layout-inflater

After upgrading from Android 4.0.2 to 4.1.2 my self created app is not working anymore.

When shooting a picture it should create a bitmap from the callback data. During the bitmap command I get an Out of memory Error.

I've found a similar problem in a google issue:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42516

> I just ran into this issue and made some experiments, my conclusion:
>
> -you can't set any drawable or color in XML and apply it with setContentView, doing so will leak the Activity
>
> fix: don't use
>   setContentView instead use 
>       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
>
> ```
> inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frontpage, (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content), true);
> ```

So I tried the fix, but it doesn't work for me. The screen stays black and I get a Camera Error -1 exception.

Here is my callback:

```
public class ScanCallback implements PictureCallback {

    MainActivity mainActivity;
    private boolean savePicture = false;

    public ScanCallback(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                data.length);
        Bitmap redrawn = bitmapPicture.copy(bitmapPicture.getConfig(), true);

        mainActivity.mCamera.startPreview();

        MainActivity.waitForCallback = false;

    }
}
```

And my main Activity.onCreate:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

        mPreview = new CameraView(this);

        mainActivity = this;

        scanCallback = new ScanCallback();

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

//      setContentView(mPreview);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
//              (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content), true);


        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }
```

That's about it. If you want to see any other code, let me know.

Any ideas how to get the fix running? Or how to avoid the error in the first place?

Comment: Do you need to have the entire picture that's been taken? You might want to downsample the bitmaps.

Comment: I need 6 200x200 squares from within the pictures, the rest can be downsampled.

Comment: Look into efficient bitmap handling, either by downsampling or break up huge bitmaps into smaller ones and handle them one by one.

Comment: As soon as I add the option parameter to the BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() the result Bitmap is NULL. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Is that options to see how big the picture is? It only reads the size first so you can see if you need to resize it. (If we are talking about the same thing). Plenty of examples, google has them too. Otherwise I guess that's another issue or update your question. Since the commenting section is turning into a chat.

Comment: Okay :) thanks, got it up and running. If any of you feels like posting an official answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look over at [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) and [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Depending on your particularly need you can either downsample the bitmaps so they are smaller or create several smaller bitmaps from one bigger and just load one by one. So you don't use that much memory.